# i want to display given data display in same Screen by using reecycler view

Tags: android

Facing fetching errors in adaper class to bind data in recycler view in same main activity screen.

I created  screen user name using edit text,dob using date picker, select dep using spinner and status using edittet and finally Submit click th above all data show in same screen activity.i am using recyler view but face errors in adaper class to bind the data in recycler view.

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dlist=new DepartmentList(Name ,DOB, Dep,Status);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(Name.getText().toString());
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.new_recycle);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Dept_Details.this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```